# Clustering Data using UPGMA Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, matrix

I am trying to implement upgma algorithm to cluster data "The UPGMA algorithm constructs a rooted tree (dendrogram) using Distance matrix like this matrix
[image: Distance Matrix]
I used this example [upgma algorithm example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPGMA).

The UPGMA Algorithm:
1- Find the smallest value from the matrix (ex: 17).
2- Grouping pairwise element (a,b).
3- Update Distance matrix based on the new group (a,b) like this
   [image: First Distance matrix Update]

[image: The generated new matrix:]

4- Repeat again from step 1.

This is my code which in fact i stopped in step 3 of updating the matrix as how i can label index 0 or any other index with a string in other words how can i know after that index 4 represent this group ((b,c),e) as example.

```
        Dictionary<int, List<double>> groups = new Dictionary<int, List<double>>();
        int nofgroups=4;
        while (nofgroups > 0)
        {
            int smallest = smallestnumber();
            positionofsmallestnumber = smallestnumposition(smallest);

            groups.Add(nofgroups, new List<double>());
            groups[nofgroups].Add(positionofsmallestnumber.X);
            groups[nofgroups].Add(positionofsmallestnumber.Y);
            groups[nofgroups].Add(smallest);
            groups[nofgroups].Add(distbcurrentandnewclusterp);

            //update
            for (int row = 0; row < distanceMatrix.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < row; col++)
                {
                    // this is line is not correct 
                    distanceMatrix[col, row] = (distanceMatrix[col, positionofsmallestnumber.X] + distanceMatrix[col, positionofsmallestnumber.Y]) / 2;
                }
            }

            //reduce the matrix
            var newdistmatrix = reducearray(positionofsmallest.X, positionofsmallest.X, distanceMatrix);
            distanceMatrix = newdistmatrix;

            nofgroups--;
        }


        //1-get small element in distance matrix
    public int smallestnumber()
    {
        int smallest = int.MaxValue;
        //access distance matrix to get smallest distance 
        for (int row = 0; row < distanceMatrix.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < row; col++)
            {

                    if (smallest > distanceMatrix[col, row])
                    {
                        smallest = distanceMatrix[col, row];
                        //positionofsmallest = new Point(row, col);
                    }

            }
        } 

        return smallest;
    }
    //2-get the position of smallest element in distance matrix
    Point positionofsmallest ;
    public Point smallestnumposition(double smallestnum)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < distanceMatrix.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < row; col++)
            {
                if (distanceMatrix[col, row] == smallestnum)
                {
                    positionofsmallest = new Point(col, row);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return positionofsmallest;
    }

    //used function to update the matrix.
    public static int[,] reducearray(int rowToRemove, int columnToRemove, int[,] originalArray)
    {
        int[,] result = new int[originalArray.GetLength(0) - 1, originalArray.GetLength(1) - 1];

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < originalArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if (i == rowToRemove)
                continue;

            for (int k = 0, u = 0; k < originalArray.GetLength(1); k++)
            {
                if (k == columnToRemove)
                    continue;

                result[j, u] = originalArray[i, k];
                u++;
            }
            j++;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

what is the best data structure can used to reduce the dimension of matrix (update it) and keeping the index of each element correct !
or how can i implement this algorithm using any other programming language then calling this code in my c# code ?
any help !
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a lot of questions here; it looks as if you're asking us to implement the whole algorithm for you, which isn't what Stack Overflow is about.

Comment: The matric decrements as 5x5, ,4x4,3x3,2x2.  So you always stop at 2x2.  The algorithm always uses two List<List<decimal>>.  One if the starting matrix and second is the results.  So after each step swap  like a bubble sort : a -> temp, b -> a, temp -> b.

Comment: @jdweng 
Thanks for your comment , but i will update values not making swap !

Comment: @AakashM Thanks for your comment, but my question is that while i was working in this algorithm, i stopped in step # 3 of updating the matrix. in this step, the index of elements will be changed every time so i asked if there is any way to update the matrix and knowing the new index of each element (a,b,c,d,e) in the matrix